# How to add a style to a DevExpress LayoutPanel in XAML

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I am using LayoutPanels inside a LayoutGroup. Is it possible to add a style to these LayoutPanels like margin background etc?

Answer (score 0):

We have answered this question at:

[Can LayoutPanels have a style?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q329066)